# Is there a way to add a line on top of a histogram?

Tags: vega-lite

My best attempt at it so far : [Direct link to Vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHnSxkeWNjCgIESBKXJjAbQ1mT9h1ADCyvIytK8xyAEFYRkx1ZzNIAAVuQlYxHR4VHGlpADYAdgBGZIAmJwgAXxDnU1DXd09kb18AUVYAJyjrQtCIqJi45WNsrKyABgBOXLACweLmt29yypx-ADNaxnhgwfNI6NiPDpx09IBWVJ30gdDh0NHnSHGPLx9pgHl4ZHQlILVlqFW2jYSwAGZkvqSgxORTeFzK118ADluLUWGA-KhkPNFq8Su9Wut4sYdskUllkkCmmYzg4wRMIdM-N50LV4B4UUTSR9MZswATjozHGiyVcKjcoABlbisOEIpELJbc5ntb7SdI9H49AAcQKcAF0iZB2DTbCNQZdJvz-IFJSUWmsZcYkmlMjkOXruQaKVAavVCI1QdKvp1ur0js5gQ4SWEnXzfH45hLUWavVitrt9odCQ6zaGplB7o9nqbmrHWX8AdJk6d9eCw9NobDEPDEcic+c898cXj2QHOcHzGmjVTdLT6fWmRjLThWw5A8TS+Ty4LhaLa1HOSsh97EvLFSrjuqNMDIAB3RiaFjGbaKwqQFCMaj4K0-JVn2IATyRuqDg0gGFqAGtjB2oHgH+6vjarU0bNFE6DwMwD7GD0dCpMW5wVPA3CaJ41A-qCAAeGFouYCDoGI1g4L+pKEOgmioUo6E4D0bz5IuYQzIwyBiJovhdqBZr-oB0xKNwqCeARkBvOOpLQcRdFQExLFsdMjacc03FEVAACOrBPB4ugeFQwlonkCGktoug4WaSjoIiQE6qqY5EsG740t+EnckpviWB63KeHgSKENw6zKZAsBeYQClhIF9SfsgADqB5HjgPwGWESEoWhJnNNhTm4ZA6CYYwRjEaJ5zSax7FlpUDHmC5vH8YJYi6SUBXmOJXKZdluU-g1jHMcVcnLli5V-gB-lqRpzBxDpIkJeYRmYBlzRmRZ0xuXVY5OPpEBqiAeRAA)

I created 2 layers with the same data, remove padding for the 'bar' layer and add a step interpolation for the 'line' layer but I can't find a way to make the line starts at the vertical axis and ends at the right of chart.

The spec (sorry I removed lines because StackOverflow doesn't want to let me post it if the ratio text/code is not enough) :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "datasets": ...,
  "width": 1130,
  "height": 438,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "opacity": 0.7
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "scale": {
            "padding": 0
          },
          "field": "Continent",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Population",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "name": "bar"
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "step",
        "strokeWidth": 3
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "axis": {},
          "field": "Continent",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "y": {
          "axis": {},
          "field": "Population",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "name": "line"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your link seems to be broken. It is also nice to use a markdown style hyperlink for those long Vega Editor URLs `[Link Text](https://theURL)`. Also can you include your spec in a code block as well.

Comment: The URL you provide is invalid. Please share the chart spec directly in the question

Comment: I hope it will be better now (sorry, my first StackOverflow question ...)

Comment: Related question in Altair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878892/drawing-line-plot-for-a-histogram Unfortunately, I don't think the current version of Vega-Lite provides an easy way to do this.